# Which sigmoid function to use for increasing contrast of an image?

Tags: image-processing, contrast, math-functions

Is there a standard sigmoidal function used to increase the contrast in a gray level bitmap?

Currently I am using the following. This would be applied to gray levels represented at values between 0 and 1 inclusive.

```
static double ContrastCurve(double val, double k = 1)
{
    Func<double,double> logistic_func = (double x) => 1.0 / (1.0 + Math.Exp(-k * (x - 0.5)));
    var low = logistic_func(0);
    var high = logistic_func(1);
    var range = high - low;
    var value = logistic_func(val);
    return (value - low) / range;
}
```

This is [the logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) applied to a value between 0 and 1 with the output normalized so that the output is also in [0...1]. This function works but it is completely arbitrary, something I just made up, so the `k` param has no official name or meaning in image processing literature and so forth.

If there is a function that is standard I would prefer that but haven't found anything that seems definitive. Code such [as this link](https://www.dfstudios.co.uk/articles/programming/image-programming-algorithms/image-processing-algorithms-part-5-contrast-adjustment/) seems as ad hoc to me.

Comment: Anthony Thyssen has a very good discussion and links to papers for the sigmoidal  contrast stretch used by **ImageMagick** here... https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#sigmoidal

Comment: Thanks this just the kind of thing I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mark Setchell's comment notes, [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#sigmoidal) uses the following function citing ["Fundamentals of Image Processing", Hany Farid](https://farid.berkeley.edu/downloads/tutorials/fip.pdf):

```
g(u) = 1 / [1 + exp(-α*u + β)]
```

scaled such that for domain [0..1] its range is [0..1].

This is essentially a two parameter version of the function defined in the code in the question above i.e. the code in the question implements the same function but makes the substitution `α = k` and `β = -k/2` which yields a one parameter function `f` where `f(0.5) = 0.5` when scaled such that `f(0) = 0` and `f(1) = 1`.